# Finding the structure of an automorphism group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, automorphism-group

> Question: Let $G=\operatorname{Aut}(\mathbb Z_4\times\mathbb Z_4)$, $c$ be an element in $G$ such that $c:(a,b)\mapsto(3a,3b)$. Prove that $\langle c\rangle\triangleleft G$, and that
>   $$G/\langle c\rangle\cong S_4\times\mathbb Z_2.$$

**My Attempt**
Rephrasing the question to matrix form, $G=\rm{GL}(2,\mathbb Z_4)$, the $c$ turns into $\left(\begin{matrix}3&0\\0&3\end{matrix}\right)$. As $c$ is a diagonal matrix, $M\langle c\rangle M^{-1}=\langle c\rangle$ for all $M$. Hence $\langle c\rangle\triangleleft G$.
Note that the RHS of the desired isomorphism is a direct product, there must be an element $d$ having order $2$ in $G/\langle c\rangle$ such that it commutes with all elements in the quotient group. One problem I need to overcome is to express the elements in the quotient group. I tried to express them as cosets, but it is hard to tackle. One possible pathway is to find this $d$ and view the quotient group $G/\langle c\rangle/\langle d\rangle$ as a permutation of $4$ elements.

Comment: You don't necesarily have $c(a, b) = (3a, 3b)$. It could be $c(a, b) = (3b, 3a)$, or $c(a, b) = (2a+b, 3a)$.

Comment: @Arthur In order to make $\langle c\rangle\triangleleft G$, $c(a,b)$ have to be $(3a,3b)$. What I meant is not $\forall c\in G, c:(1,1)\mapsto(3,3)$.

Comment: That might be. But the way the question is phrased, that's exactly what it means. You have $G$ and you have an arbitrary element $c\in G$ that fulfills $c(1, 1) = (3, 3)$. Using those assumptions, and nothing more, prove that $\langle c\rangle$ is normal in $G$. That's how I read the question, and I don't think it can, in any reasonable way, be read to mean that we _must_ have $c(a, b) = (3a, 3b)$. If that is indeed a requirement, then the question ought to be rephrased.

Comment: Sorry for that. I have rephrased my question.

Comment: You removed "$c\in G$". That doesn't help at all (that actually makes it more unclear what $c$ is). If you don't change "$c:(1, 1)\mapsto (3, 3)$" into "$c:(a, b)\mapsto (3a, 3b)$", or do something else like that, then that's not going to be an assumption you're allowed to make.

Comment: The definition of $c$ is weird. $c$ is just $-Id$.

Comment: If it's any help to you, an inverse image in $G$ of an element of $G/\langle c \rangle$ is $\left(\begin{array}{cc}1&2\\2&3\end{array}\right)$.